# JQUERY JSON FORM API LIVE SEARCH

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make live search with Jquery with the data from API, but i have some problem:

1. The suggestion still appear even the search box si empty
2. When i bluring the search box the suggestion search still appear
3. I can't submit the form with pressing the enter button, i must click the button on the from

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let api = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries/";

    $("#search").keyup( function() {

        $("#result").html('');
        let searchField = $("#search").val();
        let expression = new RegExp( searchField, "i" );
        $.getJSON( api, function( data ) {
            $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                if( value.country.search(expression) != -1 /*||  value.continent.search(expression) */  ) 
                {
                    $("#result").append(`<li class="list-group-item c">${value.country} <img src="${value.countryInfo.flag}" class="img-thumbnail"></li>`)
                }
            } );
        } );
    } );

    $("#result").on("click", "li", function() {
        $("#search").val($(this).text());
        $("#result").html('');
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row py-4">
                <div class="search__wrapper col-12 text-center text-center">
                    <form id="covidSearch">
                        <i class="fw-bolder text-center fs-6 font-monospace">API by <a target="_blank" class="link-dark" href="https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries/">disease.sh</a></i>
                        <h4>Search by Country</h4>
                        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Country Name" class="text-muted fs-6">
                        <button type="submit" class="fw-bold text-white">Search</button> <br>
                        <!-- LOADING ANIMATION WILL BE HERE -->
                    </form>
                    <!-- LIVE SEARCH SUGGESTION -->
                    <ul class="list-group text-center fw-bolder suggestionSearch" id="result"></ul> 
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using jquery i want the a div to hide when the input is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923774/using-jquery-i-want-the-a-div-to-hide-when-the-input-is-empty)

Comment: When I checked the JSFiddle, Your Queries 1 and 2 are operational.